# How to store user likes (for an event app) in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to store user likes in Firestore for my event app. I thought my current implementation was working well until I tested the app on 2 devices simultaneously. I found that when clicking like on an event on 2 devices at the same time (or close to) lead to a like not being recorded for one of the users i.e. the user uid would not be stored in the likedBy array.

** I wrote my first line of code 3 months ago, so please be gentle. I have searched stackoverflow already and am currently using the database structure suggested in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56501909/remember-the-status-of-the-like-button-after-re-opening-in-flutter):

```
Events
----docID (each individual event)
------likedBy[uid1, uid2, uid3...] // This document also contains the event data model. Location, tags, title etc.
```

I don't have great understanding of cloud firestore, but I would have thought you could have many simultaneous writes to an array but this doesn't seem to be the case for me. The Heart class below is used in the pages where a user can like an event.

```dart
import 'package:/models/quest_model.dart';
import 'package:/services/database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Heart extends StatelessWidget {
  final DatabaseService database;
  final QuestModel questModel;  
  final List likedByCopy;g
  final bool isLikedByUser;

  Heart({

    @required this.likedByCopy,
    @required this.isLikedByUser,
    @required this.database,
    @required this.questModel,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          isLikedByUser ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
          color: isLikedByUser ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.white,
          size: 35,
        ),
        onPressed: () {

            if (isLikedByUser) {
              likedByCopy.remove(database.uid);

              addQuestData(context, likedByCopy);
            } else {
              likedByCopy.add(database.uid);
              addQuestData(context, likedByCopy);
            }

        });
  }

  Future<void> addQuestData(BuildContext context, List likedByCopy) async {
    try {
      await database.updateUserLikedQuests(
          documentId: questModel.id,
          questModel: QuestModel(
            likedBy: likedByCopy,
            id: questModel.id,            
          ));
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Below is an implementation of the Heart class in the Event detail page, where trailing is a parameter of ListTile:

```dart
trailing: StreamBuilder<QuestModel>(
            stream:
                widget.database.questStream(documentId: widget.questModel.id),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
                final questModel = snapshot.data;
                final likedByCopy = []..addAll(questModel.likedBy);
                final isLikedByUser = likedByCopy.contains(widget.database.uid);
                return Heart(
                  database: widget.database,
                  likedByCopy: likedByCopy,
                  isLikedByUser: isLikedByUser,
                  questModel: widget.questModel,
                );
              }
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Text('Waiting');
              }
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }));
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think that your issue stems from the fact that you are generating a new array and sending it to Firestore instead of just appending the username with the `arrayUnion()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the race condition problem by using arrayUnion and arrayRemove as shown in the updated Heart class below:

```dart
class Heart extends StatelessWidget {
  final DatabaseService database;
  final QuestModel questModel;
  final bool isLikedByUser;

  Heart({
    @required this.isLikedByUser,
    @required this.database,
    @required this.questModel,
  })  : assert(questModel != null),
        assert(database != null),
        assert(isLikedByUser != null);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          isLikedByUser ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
          color: isLikedByUser ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.white,
          size: 35,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          isLikedByUser
              ? database.arrayRemove(questModel.id, database.uid)
              : database.arrayUnion(questModel.id, database.uid);
        });
  }


}
```